# windows RT / Universal app, Text to speech "Save as Mp3"

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, text-to-speech, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make a speech to text universal app but got stuck on one thing. I looked all over the internet and could not find a proper solution which works.. So I came here.. Basically I want the app to save what ever is in the text box as mp3. Here is my code so far:

```
 private void Speak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpeakText(Text.Text);
    }
    public async void SpeakText(string TTS)
            {
                SpeechSynthesizer ttssynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

                //Set the Voice/Speaker
                using (var Speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer())
                {
                    Speaker.Voice = (SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female));

                    ttssynthesizer.Voice = Speaker.Voice;
                }

                SpeechSynthesisStream ttsStream = await ttssynthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(TTS);

                //play the speech
                MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
                media.SetSource(ttsStream, " ");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can save `SpeechSynthesisStream` as just a .wav file.  Then you can re-encode it to anything you like using a `MediaTranscoder` class.

[MSDN: Media Transcoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.transcoding.aspx)

[Sample Project using Media Transcoder -- use it as a refeence](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-transcode-sample-f7ba5269)

---

Some extra help saving the stream to a wav file : [SpeakText.xaml.cpp](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/981ED27/FA732CB1)

Comment: How do is save SpeechSynthesStrem as a .wav file? Sorry I'm new to this stuff

Comment: @ProgrammingPotato See the cpp file that was link, it is under the event handler `BtnSaveToFile_Click`

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for c# code, not c++. I will just leave it until I learn more about programming.

Comment: @ProgrammingPotato It uses the same functions.  It can almost be converted 1:1.  Just ignore the `^` and you will realize that `Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer` is the same crap as `Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer`

Comment: @ProgrammingPotato Or you can search SO on how to write a buffer to a file.  Pretty sure a lot of answers are available.